# Dynamic functions creation from json, python

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and I need to create class on the fly from the following json:

```
{
    "name": "ICallback",
    "functions": [
        {
            "name": "OnNavigation", 
            "parameters": [
                {"name":"Type", "type": "int", "value": "0"},
                {"name":"source", "type": "int", "value": "0"},
                {"name":"tabId", "type": "string", "value": ""},
                {"name":"Url", "type": "string", "value": ""},
                {"name":"Context", "type": "int", "value": "0"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I found how to create class, but I don't understand how to create methods on the fly.
For now function will just raise `NotImplemented` exception.

Comment: It's a interesting question, but what do you want the method(s) to *do*?  Your json doesn't specify.

Comment: from config file or ui

Comment: it's not a full json. Other part of the json will describe a derived class with the implementation. But implementation is easier as it will be predefined in the code simple methods calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already know to create a class:

```
class Void(object):
    pass

kls = Void()
```

You want to create a method from a JSON, but I'm going to do it from a string that can be created from the JSON:

```
from types import MethodType

d = {}
exec "def OnNavigation(self, param): return param" in d

kls.OnNavigation = MethodType(d["OnNavigation"], kls)
# setattr(kls, "OnNavigation", MethodType(d["OnNavigation"], kls))

print kls.OnNavigation("test")
```

Should output *test*.

Comment: One more question. kls.OnNavigation = MethodType(d["OnNavigation"], kls)
How can I generate OnNavigation dynamically, I don't know how many functions I have in class, so I need   "kls.OnNavigation =" dynamic as well, or I miss something

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr

`kls.OnNavigation = X` is the same as `setattr(kls, "OnNavigation", X)`.